# Steps involved in hosting a website

Tags: web-hosting, domains, looking-for-hosting

I work as a Java / Java EE developer. I have built / maintained websites for the companies that I work for , but I have never been involved in the end-to-end process (Eg: procuring servers , registering the website etc).

I thought of building and hosting a website for my uncle. He sells few financial products and he has to travel a lot around the city that I live to market and sell his products. I wanted to help him by building a website for him which would hopefully allow people to yeah out to him rather than him going and searching for customers.

I am not quite sure as to where I should start -

1) Whom should I contact for hosting my web application - this is not a very critical app , hence a low cost solution would be suffice.Are there any low cost cloud based solutions available?
2) How can I register a domain and how much does it normally cost?
3) How can I copyright my website and its contents?

Regards,

Comment: This question is way too broad and its parts have been asked here before. You can learn more about finding hosting [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements). Copyrights [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=copyright). You can find out more about registering domains with a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=domain%20registration%20basics).